# Lookup data updates in Content Search Web Part / Search Results

Tags: search-results, lookup-column, content-search-web-part, edit

I am using a content search web part to serve up text content and hyperlinks from a list (We will call this the main list). Everything is displaying as expected. One of my fields is a lookup column, mapped to the ID and displaying the title from the lookup list (let's call this list the source list). Recently we had to change the title of one of the items in the source list.

Upon changing the title, all items referencing that ID in the main list updated to reflect the new title. In this case we changed Blog to Article. 48 hours later the Content Search Web Part and Search results still displayed the data with Blog, despite that not matching the list views of the data in the main list.

Now I ran a reindex on the main list and this did resolve the immediate issue. My question is for future updates. Should my process include a reindex of the main list or, as I originally expected should this update automatically?

I suspect the crawl did not find a change since the data in the main list was technically unchanged, and the result does not consider the source list value change in the result for the main list, however I want to be certain I document and communicate the expectation correctly.